# Image display on pop up window

Tags: python, pywebview

I am working on a windows desktop app using pywebview. I want to achieve a full image on the start up window for 5 secs. A very good example Easeus application on start up it shows an Image like this;
[image]

These are my python codes;

```
import webview
import requests
import tkinter as tk

# initializing URL
url = "http:127.0.0.1:81"
timeout = 10
try:
# requesting URL
request = requests.get(url,
                       timeout=timeout)
webview.create_window('Hello', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/', resizable=True)
webview.start()

# catching exception
except (requests.ConnectionError,
    requests.Timeout) as exception:
window = tk.Tk()
greeting = tk.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter")
greeting.pack()
```

Comment: I don't know `webview` - but if you want to display popup with `tkinter` and `tk.Label( image=...)` then you can use `window.after(5000, window.destroy)` and after 5000 ms (5 seconds) it will run `window.destroy()` and it will close window.

Comment: I don't know `webview` but if it runs HTML then it may need `JavaScript` to reload or close web page.

Comment: in official documentation for [pywebview](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/) I found example [destroy window](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/examples/destroy_window.html#destroy-window) - and it closes window after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In official documentation for [pywebview](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/) I found example [destroy window](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/examples/destroy_window.html#destroy-window). It closes window after 5 seconds.

```
import webview
import time

def destroy(window):
    # show the window for a few seconds before destroying it:
    time.sleep(5)
    print('Destroying window..')
    window.destroy()
    print('Destroyed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = webview.create_window('Destroy Window Example', 'https://pywebview.flowrl.com/hello')
    webview.start(destroy, window)
    print('Window is destroyed')
```

---

But if you use `tkinter` then you could use `tk.Label(image=...)` - and `window.after(5000, window.destroy)` to close window after 5000ms (5 seconds)

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

img = tk.PhotoImage(file='image.png')  # has to be `file=`

tk.Label(image=img).pack()

window.after(5000, window.destroy)     # `destroy` without `()`

window.mainloop()
```

For `.jpg` it may need `PIL.ImageTk`

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='image.jpg')  # has to be `file=`

tk.Label(image=img).pack()

window.after(5000, window.destroy)     # `destroy` without `()`

window.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also use pywebview to display HTML with image, and with tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;https://...">` and it will redirect to other page after 5 second

**index.html**

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;https://stackoverflow.com">

<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna">Lenna</a> from Wikipedia:<br>

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png">
```

**main.py**

```
import webview

webview.create_window('Example', 'index.html')
webview.start()
```

And if you use this method then you don't need Python to start it.
You can use bash/batch script with `chrome.exe index.html`

Comment: it has worked perfectly, but now I want it to show my website after the image has been shown for 5 secs

Comment: after closing image run `webview` with your page. If you display image using `webview` then you will have to do it inside `destroy()`. If you display image using `tkinter` then you will have to do it after `window.mainloop()`. Eventually you could use `webview` to display web page with image and with JavaScript code which chagen `document.location = 'http:// ...` after 5 seconds (using `setTimer()`) - and it could load page with application. But this way will work even in normal web browser and it doesn't need Python.

Comment: on web page you can also use tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url_to_new_page">` to reload other page after 5 seconds. [HTML meta http-equiv Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)

Comment: if it helped then you can mark my aswer as accepted.